# Tracking method for QGIS Plugin Usage

Tags: http-headers, qgis, pyqgis, usage-tracking

I have a QGIS3 python plugin that I would like to track its users' usage. Is it possible to add a http request to the headers? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest obstacle is that an http request package should be installed (like `requests`). This easy to do in the osgeo4w shell for a particular installation of QGIS, but it can't be done from within a plugin (as far as I can tell).

However, there's nothing to stop you from inserting `requests.post(path,headers,data)` into your plugin script files.